# Indexes and Deleting statements

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms, ddl, dml

I just want to know that I have a table with  more than 1000 records and I also have a few indexes. I want to delete the data from the table. If I use either delete or truncate, what will happen to the indexes. In other words are the indexes also deleted if we use any of these statements. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you change or the delete the data in a table then the table structure is NOT affected by that.

To change the table structure itself you would have to drop the table completely or alter it with specific commands like adding indexes or columns and things like that.

The index is a mechanism to get records faster by building an optimised map to the data. If records get changed that map has to be regenerated or you could say corrected.

So if you delete records then the index of your table is not correct anymore because it does not match the data. So very time you change something in a table the index automatically gets adjusted.

That is the reason why indexes make selects very fast. But if you add a lot of them, then inserts and updates and delete get slowert because the indexes need to be updated on those operations.

But the index definition does not get changed - the data the index contains changes. Exactly like in a table. By changing the data of a table - you don't change the structure of a table.

Comment: Can u please explain a little more in detail ..Im sorry i dont have enough knowledge about indexes so I would highly appreciate it if you can explain it further. I kind of got confused when u said that the indexes get recalculated after the deletion. Please explain.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: note that "table structure" includes indexes etc that refer to the table

Comment: You never directly interact with the data of the index, Select queries on the table MAY read from the index if mysql decides that will be faster than reading directly from the table. The actions performed by mysql during Insert/Update/Delete queries on the table MUST also change the data in the index to match the table, but you the programer don't have to do anything. In fact, the only thing you can do to affect what occurs is disable / drop the index